# How to say "See you then" and "You see then" in French?

Tags: anglais, expressions, ordre-des-mots

How would I say each ("see you then" and "you see, then") given that in French the object comes before the verb?

Would it be “*vous voyez alors*” in each case?

The first statement would be made when parting after deciding on meeting next at a predetermined time. The second statement says if the second person sees the logic behind something after some event or explanation. I agree things are sometimes said in different ways in different languages. How would I say these then in French?

Comment: I don't see any french in the question for now? english does not translate literally to french :)

Comment: I've edited your question to add what you said in your comment. You can edit the question to rephrase it if you like. You can always edit your own question. Welcome to French.se

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Effectivement en français on doit exprimer le sujet qui n'est pas exprimé en anglais dans "*see you then*". Le plus proche de "*see you then*"  serait :

- « On se voit le [mention de la date]. »
- « On se voit [mention du jour]. »
- « On se voit à ce moment là. »

Dans « *you see* », *you* étant sujet, on dirait tout simplement « tu vois ».

Pour ce qui est de *then* en français on peut avoir besoin de mots différents pour exprimer les deux sens qu'il a en anglais dans les phrases que tu soumets.

- Sens temporel ("*see you then*") : alors, à ce moment-là.
- Sens logique ("*you see, then*") : alors, donc.

Mais le plus fréquent en français pour exprimer l'anglais "see you* est d'employer une locution qui introduite pas la préposition à :

- « À lundi. »
- « À la semaine porchaine. »
- « À plus tard. » (Devenu « À plus » depuis une ou deux décennies.)

Ce n'est pas possible si l'expression de temps est « alors » ou « à ce moment là. »

---

In French we can't omit the subject as it is done in English in "see you then", so I've given you various possibilities. The latest being, to me, the least usual. In "you see, then", "you" is subject and we'd just say "*tu vois*".

As for "then" in French we might have to use different words in both cases. "*Alors*" can be used in both cases, whether "then" is temporal ("at that time") or logical ("in that case"). When temporal you can also use "*à ce moment là*".  When logical when ca also use "*donc*".

Comment: Merci beaucoup!

Comment: "On doit exprimer le sujet" en francais.  Oui et non.  A plus tard...  A+ ;-)

Comment: The question really should be about English. "See you then" is not correct (complete) English.  It is an abbreviation (and slang) for "I'll see you then."  Do not look for a literal translation of such abbreviated speech, or you will be sorely disappointed.

Comment: @Drew: il n'y a pas de verbe dans "à plus", pas de verbe, donc pas de sujet. Je m'autocite : "Mais le plus fréquent en français pour exprimer l'anglais "see you* est d'employer une locution qui introduite pas la préposition à :

    « À lundi. »
    « À la semaine porchaine. »
    « À plus tard. » (Devenu « À plus » depuis une ou deux décennies.)"

Comment: @Drew: Both "see you" and "à plus tard/à tout à l'heure" are abbreviations and colloquial (I wouldn't say slang, but we can discuss it on ELL), **but** in English the verb is kept in the abbreviation, in French it isn't, and that seemed to be a problem for OP.

Comment: @Laure -- je suis d'accord.  Ce que je voulais souligner c'est qu'il ne s'agit pas de **"see you" vs "you see"**.  "See you" manque un sujet.  "You see" est une phrase complete.  Il s'agit d'une question (d'apprentissage) d'anglais, pas de francais.  On ne peut pas comprendre la difference entre "see you" and "you see" sans savoir que le premier n'est qu'une abbreviation.  (Tout comme "Later!" et "A plus tard".)  Il me semble que Chaudhry n'a peut-etre pas compris, et pense que "see you" n'est qu'une inversion de l'ordre entre sujet et verbe.  (Et il a parle d'*objet* pour "vous voyez".)

Comment: @Laure -- I don't think that was the problem for the OP.  I think his problem was not understanding that, in "see you", "you" is the object and, in "you see", "you" is the subject.  He spoke of French putting the object before the verb, but he then proposed "vous voyez" for both.  I don't think that the fact that French keeps a verb in abbreviations is important here -- it is unrelated to the OP's confusion, IMO.  But I could be wrong.  And you are right about colloquialism vs slang, here.